# Logging when ASP.NET MVC session times out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

If the user voluntarily logs out, I log this. You can see the logs of this controller below. If the session period has expired, I am redirected to the login page. But I cannot log because the LogOut controller is not working. Is there a way to log the session only when it times out, rather than when the user requests it?

Controller :

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    try
    {
        LogProcessService logProcessService = new LogProcessService();

        LogProcess logProcess = new LogProcess();
        UsersDetails usersDetails = Session["UsersDetails"] as UsersDetails;

        logProcess.kullanici = usersDetails.username;
        logProcess.sayfa = "Çıkış";
        logProcess.islem = "Çıkış";
        logProcess.tarih = DateTime.Now;
        logProcess.logText = "Çıkış Yapıldı";
        logProcessService.InsertLog(logProcess);

        Session.Abandon();

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
    }
}
```

`web.config`:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState>
```